# Express response, async with recursive function

Tags: javascript, express, recursion, callback, cloudinary

I'm trying to fetch all photos from Cloudinary, but there's a limit of 500 elements per call.

There's an attribute called `next_cursor` when it's present in the call, you can use it as pagination.

I did it recursively but when I try to send the response in Express is out of scope, any ideas on how to response with the result of the recursive function?

Thanks!

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;

const { cloudinarySettings } = require("../config/cloudinary_config");

router.get("/statistics", async (req, res) => {
    function list_resources(results, next_cursor = null) {
        cloudinary.api.resources(
            {
                resource_type: "image",
                mex_results: 500,
                next_cursor: next_cursor,
            },
            function (err, res) {
                console.log(err);
                res.resources.forEach(function (resource) {
                    results.push(resource);
                });

                if (res.next_cursor) {
                    list_resources(results, res.next_cursor);
                } else {
                    return res.status(200).json(results)
                }
            }
        );
    }

    const results = [];
    list_resources(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might break the problem up a bit differently, and make a simpler recursive function which returns the results rather than modifying an array passed in.  I would also move the function out of the `router.get` callback for cleanliness.

So it might look like this:

```js
const listResources = async ({resource_type, max_results = 500, next_cursor = null} = {}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cloudinary .api .resources (
      {resource_type, max_results, next_cursor}, 
      async (err, {resources, next_cursor}) => {
        try {
          if (err) {reject (err)}
          else resolve ([
            ...resources, 
            ...(next_cursor ? await listResources ({resource_type, max_results, next_cursor}) : [])
          ])
        } catch (err) {reject (err)}
      }
    )
  })
}

router.get('/statistics', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const results = await listResources ({resource_type: 'image'})
    res .status (200) .json (results)
  } catch (err) {
    console .warn (err)
    res .status (404) // or 500, or whatever, based on error
  }
})
```

The most interesting part is this:

```js
    resolve ([
      ...resources, 
      ...(next_cursor ? await listResources ({resource_type, max_results, next_cursor}) : [])
    ])
```

If we get back a `next_cursor` value, we append the result of a recursive call using it to our current results before resolving it.  If we don't get one, we append an empty array.

It would be nice to be able to write this arguably simpler cloudinary callback function:

```js
    async (err, {resources, next_cursor}) => err 
      ? reject (err)
      : resolve ([
          ...resources, 
          ...(next_cursor ? await listResources ({resource_type, max_results, next_cursor}) : [])
        ])
```

avoiding the `try-catch` and `if-else` blocks.  But I can't find a straightforward way to do that and pass the error back through to the function initially calling `listResources`.

You can test this in your browser with dummy implementations of `cloudinary` and `router` in this snippet:

```js
const listResources = async ({resource_type, max_results, next_cursor = null}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cloudinary.api.resources(
      {resource_type, max_results, next_cursor}, 
      async (err, {resources, next_cursor}) => {
        try {
          if (err) {reject (err)}
          else resolve ([
            ...resources, 
            ...(next_cursor ? await listResources ({resource_type, max_results, next_cursor}) : [])
          ])
        } catch (err) {reject (err)}
      }
    )
  })
}

router.get('/statistics', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const results = await listResources ({resource_type: 'image', max_results: 3})
    res .status (200) .json (results)
  } catch (err) {
    console .warn (err)
    res .status (500) // or whatever, based on error
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// Dummy implementations for testing:

const cloudinary = (() => {
  const vals = [{t: 'image', id: 1,  v: 'a'}, {t: 'image', id: 2,  v: 'b'}, {t: 'image', id: 3,  v: 'c'}, {t: 'pdf',   id: 4,  v: 'd'}, {t: 'image', id: 5,  v: 'e'}, {t: 'image', id: 6,  v: 'f'}, {t: 'video', id: 7,  v: 'g'}, {t: 'image', id: 8,  v: 'h'}, {t: 'image', id: 9,  v: 'i'}, {t: 'image', id: 10, v: 'j'}, {t: 'image', id: 11, v: 'k'}, {t: 'image', id: 12, v: 'l'}]; 
  const last = (xs) => xs.length ? xs[xs.length - 1] : undefined; 
  return {api: {
    resources: ({resource_type, max_results, next_cursor = 0} , fn) => {
      const res = vals .filter (({t, id}) => t == resource_type && id > next_cursor).slice(0, max_results)
//      fn (next_cursor == 3 ? 'houston, we have a problem' : null, {  // *** use to test an error condition ***
      fn (null, {
        resources: res, 
        ...(res.length > 0 && last(res).id < last(vals).id ? {next_cursor: last(res).id} : {})
      })
    }
  }}
})()

const router = {
  get: (path, fn) =>
    fn (
      {},
      {status: (n) => {
        console.log(`returning ${n} for request to ${path}`)
        return {
          json: val => console.log(`Body: \n${JSON.stringify(val, null, 4)}`)
        }
      }}
    )
}
</script>
```

If you uncomment the alternative line in the dummy cloudinary code and comment the previous one, you can see the behavior when `cloudinary .api .resources` throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your `list_resources` function to return a promise as follows and then use `async-await` to wait for the results before submitting the `res` back.

```
router.get("/statistics", async (req, res) => {
    async function list_resources(results, next_cursor = null) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            cloudinary.api.resources(
                {
                    resource_type: "image",
                    mex_results: 500,
                    next_cursor: next_cursor,
                },
                function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        resolve();
                        
                    } else {
                        res.resources.forEach(function (resource) {
                            results.push(resource);
                        });

                        if (res.next_cursor) {
                            list_resources(results, res.next_cursor).then(() => resolve());
                        } else {
                            resolve();
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            );
        });
    }

    const results = [];
    await list_resources(results);
    return res.status(200).json(results);
});
```